# SQL distinct column with sum of corresponding value

Tags: sql

[image: brands]

Given this data as an example - How do I find out the amount of units per brand?

I'd like to query so the data I receive is

Brand -- Units

Apple -> 32

Samsung -> 13

Android -> 29

Comment: `SUM(units)`, `GOUP BY`. Please show us your current attempt.

Comment: I was using  ` select distinct brand, sum(units)` Question answered thanks for your time

Comment: You rarely never do SELECT DISTINCT when you do GROUP BY, because the GROUP BY eliminates duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following, using [`GROUP BY` with `SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum):

```
SELECT brand, SUM(units) AS Units
FROM table_name
GROUP BY brand
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4d140420aa512100aa54d897434ed22)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below script

```
SELECT Brand Brand, SUM(units) UnitsPerBrand
FROM table_name
GROUP BY brand
```

This will give you an output  as below

```
Brand   UnitsPerBrand
Apple       32
Samsung     5
Android     29
```